# Generate a code with the unique id which will be generated after the saving the object into database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, logic

I will try to explain if it is not clear please tell.

I have a requirement where I need to generate a code(which is an attribute of an object) that will be a combination of some `string + (unique id generated after saving the object into DB)`.

The problem is that I will not be knowing the id of that object before saving that object and that attribute refers to a not null column in the table.
So is there a way by which I can know the id which will be generated before saving it?

I am using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Per specification, the ID must be assigned to the Entity after calling EntityManager.persist.

This means you will have the ID after you call save() and then you can generate the unique id.

The INSERT statement will be executed on before commit not when calling save(). But take care there is saveAndFlush() that will execute the INSERT.

Comment: if after calling save() I will get the id then, one way is that I can insert any random string for the first time and then update the field one more time by calling save. is there another way where I don't have to call save twice?

Comment: Use a non-automated random string as a second "identifier". This can be any random string you generate but you get around the problem of needing to save() twice since you programmatically know the ID before save(). What this means is that you have an entity id generated by your persistence library and a separate identifier that you actually use for identification.

Comment: Why do you have to update the filed a second time?

Comment: @aeee98 how can i know the id before save()?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli when i am saving for the first time i will get the id and using that id after generating the code i am updating the entity so that my requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: that's perfect but then you don't have to call save again if your code is in the same transaction

Comment: okay even if i call save first time and then update the field afterwards without calling the save JPA will update the field?

Comment: Yes that's how JPA works. Read https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/